# Logic for stacking behaviour in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, z-index

I'm trying to write some javascript that will stack objects by setting z-index.

Test Case:
http://christophermeyers.name/stacker/

I've hacked that together, but I'd like to extrapolate that behavior to something a little more logical. That is:

Given x number of elements, when element C is moved to the top, all elements above that element must move down 1, while all elements below that element should remain in place.

Comment: It seems like your example already meets your requirements.  Can you give an example using your red, green, blue boxes so we can reproduce the problem and tell us what behavior you want?

Comment: If you click on green, then red, then red again, you'll see green falls below blue. That behavior is incorrect.

Additionally, the example is hard-coded for this particular situation (number of elements, etc). I was hoping to figure out the logic to handle any number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

A "linked list" makes for a good data structure when you're doing this kind of thing. Keep track of the order of your stackable elements via a series of simple nodes..

```
// ListNode
{
    value: {}
    next: {<ListNode>}
}
```

..and update the sequence as new nodes are added or selected.

I have posted a working example of a list being used for depth sorting at the following URL:

> http://aethermedia.net/sandbox/depth-sorting.html

Sorry I don't have time to pull up a more appropriate tutorial =/